# Programmatically Create Button to URL

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

I've managed to create a simple rounded rect button in Xcode through code but I'm having a little trouble actually getting it to do more what I want.

Ideal situation is a custom button type with image in both states as image.png linking to a URL (say www.google.com) can anyone help me out? I presume I need to write a method to do the link. That I can handle, just not sure how to hook it up without Interface Builder (targetting iOS)

Existing Code

```
           UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(supporturl) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 50);
        [btn setTitle:@"Support and Help" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't realised I missed that! iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 150.0f, 50.0f)];
[btn setTitle:@"Support and Help" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(openWebPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
[btn release];
```

and in function

```
-(void) openWebPage
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```